# Adding swift file to new view controller in xCode? (easy)

Tags: swift, xcode6, viewcontroller

I'm just starting out in xCode 6, and I can't seem to figure out how to add a new swift-file to the new view controllers I add in the interface builder.

Any tips on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Add a new Cocoa Touch class.  Choose **File->New->File...** from the menu.  Give this new class a name such as "ViewController2" and set the **Subclass of:** pop down to *UIViewController*.  The file "ViewController2.swift" will be created.

[image]

[image]

2. Click on your new View Controller in Interface Builder.  In the *Identity Inspector* (on the right in Xcode) set the **Custom Class** for the View Controller to "ViewController2".[image]

Comment: The custom class won't show up in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: Had to make sure the view controller button was pushed on the view in the view controller (the yellow one on the top of each view in the storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

If your custom class isn't showing up in the Identity Inspector, your files may have been moved or saved in the wrong folder. I would delete them from your project and try again, this time letting the files be saved wherever they are automatically. Good luck!