# How can I call a segue in a new view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have two views.

[image: The Image of the storyboard]

When I click "Sign Up" button the second view appears. When I click "Turn back" button the first view appears. It's OK.

Now I would like to call a function when I click on "Be member" button. This function will be able to send the data in the fields above it by connecting a database. However I could not create a segue.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you wanna segue to the second view controller or be able to call a function in the second view controller? your question is not clear

Comment: I want to be able to call a function in the second view controller.

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have added a second ViewController in the Storyboard, and you now need to add a corresponding `ViewController2.swift` file.  See here:  [How to add ViewController2.swift file for second ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962957/1630618)
2. Once you have that, you can <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the button to the source code of your `ViewController2` to add an `@IBAction` for the button.
3. You shouldn't be using a standard segue to return to your first ViewController when **Turn Back** is pressed.  Instead you should use an *unwind segue*.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You need to write a clear, coherent description of what you are trying to do, with enough detail so that we know both what your goals are and **specifically** what you are trying that isn't working.

It is not at all clear what you are asking. Since you mention dragging, I *think* you are asking how to create a segue link in IB (Interface Builder) rather than how to invoke a segue in code.

How will you invoke this segue you are trying to create? From a single button, or from code? If from a button, will clicking the button always invoke the segue, and without needing any other decision making? If so, just control-drag from the button to the target scene in IB. That will create a segue and connect it to your button.

Comment: When I CTRL+drag from the second view, Xcode does not allow it to be created in ViewController.swift.

Comment: Views and view controllers are 2 different things. Make sure to say view controller when you are referring to a view controller. A view is a UIView or an object that is a subclass of UIView. A View Controller is an object that is a subclass of UIView**Controller**. They do very different jobs.

Comment: You don't control-drag to **create** a new view controller. You should create your new view controller in IB first, then control-drag from your first view controller onto your second view controller to create the segue.